# Why controller is not getting bound to angular app variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why ngController scheduleController is not getting bound to page. However same is working in [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-in-60-ish-minutes-the-ebook) video (@29th minute)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="scheduleController">
    <div class="container">
        <select ng-model="test" ng-options="schedule for schedule in scheduler.scheduleType"> 
        </select>
        {{value}}
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function scheduleController($scope) {
                $scope.scheduler = {
                    scheduleType: ['One time', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'
                        , 'Monthly Relative', 'Yearly', 'Year long']
                };
                $scope.value = 'Shantanu';
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using AngularJS v1.4.1

Comment: How do you know its not bound?

Comment: Same dropdown worked for me when I was using nginit however stopped working when I moved this code into controller. See my previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Angular version 1.3 or up, you have to manually register your controller to your app. That means you can't have `ng-app=""`, but you need to have, for instance, `ng-app="myApp"`, and have:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("scheduleController", scheduleController);
```